# How do I load a random image from an array in a JavaScript file into HTML every time the page refreshes?

Tags: javascript, html, image, random, generator

This is what I have so far. But when I run it, an error states that '$' was used before it was defined. Also, no images appear on screen. And I do no want to have the 'url(http://bukk.it/', since I have all the images in the project folder.

```js
var images = ["img/1.jpg", "img/2.jpg", "img/3.jpg", "img/4.jpg", "img/5.jpg", "img/6.jpg"];


$('#randomImage').css({'background-image': 'url(http://bukk.it/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>47</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="randomImage"/>
    
    <script type="text/js" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to include and initialize jQuery before using it. Here's a tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery is not defined, but you don't have to use it.
This will work:

```
var images = ["img/1.jpg", "img/2.jpg", "img/3.jpg", "img/4.jpg", "img/5.jpg", "img/6.jpg"];

var randomName = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

document.getElementById("randomImage").style.backgroundImage = "url('http://bukk.it/" + randomName + "')"
```

Comment: Thanks Amit! And also can the images be from a folder of images in the project, instead of the "url('http://bukk.it/"? How can I get rid of this part and still make the images work?

Comment: You can use `"url('./path/to/image/'...` And read more about [HTML File Paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).

Comment: And is it possible to do this with local folders within the project?

Comment: I am still a bit confused. This is for a Chrome extension I'm building where images from a folder are generated every time the extension is clicked, but nothing shows up except an empty box

Comment: Yes. And again, read about HTML File Paths: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp
The answers to your questions are there